# Call JavaScript from C# object in Xamarin

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin

I have been able to call JavaScript from C# inside the `MainActivity` but I'm trying to do so from an object. The majority of my app runs inside a WebView, my JavaScript calls to my C# Interface invoking an asynchronous function and when it's complete I would like to call back to my JavaScript but am unable to do so. Here is my current setup:
In my `MainActivity` I setup my WebView as such:

```
browser = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.mainView);
browser.SetInitialScale(1);
browser.SetWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
browser.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
browser.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
{
    WebView.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
browser.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);
browser.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
browser.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSCSMedium(this, ref browser), "Android");
browser.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/web/index.html");
```

Then inside the JSCSMedium object I have an asynch function:

```
[Export]
[JavascriptInterface]
public void SyncApps()
{
    Task t = Task.Run(() => {

        IList<ApplicationInfo> tempApps = Application.Context.PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MatchDirectBootAware);

        string packageName = "";
        string appName = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < tempApps.Count(); i++)
        {
            packageName = tempApps[i].PackageName;
            appName = tempApps[i].LoadLabel(manager);
            var root = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(root, "system");
            filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, packageName);

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            }

            filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, "icon.png");
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Drawable icon = tempApps[i].LoadIcon(Application.Context.PackageManager);
                BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable)icon;
                CreateAppIcon(bd.Bitmap, packageName);
            }

            Intent intent = Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            if (intent != null)
            {
                apps.Add(tempApps[i]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If I don't do the C# as an async function it runs and returns data fine, but this process takes a bit of time and blocks the app temporarily. Inside my `MainActivity` I can call JavaScript just fine with:

```
browser.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: alert('fooBar');", null);
```

But `browser` is not accessible inside the `JSCSMedium`. I've tried passing the `browser` object as a reference and normally but it throws an exception stating that the `EvaluateJavascript` function must be called on the same thread as where it was instantiated. I've also tried sending a reference of my `MainActivity` to the `JSCSMedium` and call a function inside the `MainActivity` to run the `EvaluateJavascript` but it seems to do nothing. No error, not crash, just nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Task.Run` forces the code to run in the thread pool, and `browser.EvaluateJavascript` needs to run on the main thread.

You have at least two options here, depending on your needs:

1) Run the EvaluateJavascript call inside the `Task.Run` block with something like:

```
var h = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
h.Post(() => browser.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: alert('fooBar');", null));
```

2) Run the EvaluateJavascript call outside the `Task.Run` block:

```
[Export]
[JavascriptInterface]
public async void SyncApps()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {

    //...

    });

    browser.EvaluateJavascript("javascript: alert('fooBar');", null);
}
```

Not really sure if you can change the return type of `SyncApps()`. If JS doesn't complain, you better change that too.

Comment: I think the first option is going to be my best bet. I'll play around with it when I get the chance. Thank you.

Comment: If I implement your first option it just does nothing. No error, and doesn't make the call. I tried switching my `WebView` to a reference but that didn't help. If I place it outside the `Task.Run` without changing my declaration for `SyncApps()` it makes the call, but immediately, not after the Task.Run has completed. If I change my coding to match your second choice, it crashes with 'unhandled exception`.

Comment: Interesting. Anything else you can add about the unhandled exception? What is the problem there?

Comment: I am still getting used to error handling. Somehow casting the whole function as `async` had messed up the typecasting of my `BitmapDrawable` for non launchable apps. I moved that to inside the check for `LaunchIntent` it worked perfectly. Not sure how that affected it. And I did have to combine them. I rewrote my async function to match yours, but if I move the `EvaluateJavascript` outside of the block it calls it before completion of the `Task.Run` block. The handler inside the `Task.Run` block of the rewritten async function works like a charm though.